Restoring ag grid state from a grid state object programatically
I'm currently attempting to use ag grid's 'api.getState()' functionality to get the state for a grid, and store it in a database. Once states are stored I'd like the ability to programatically apply grid state to a grid from these stored states.
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-state/ this shows how they intend it to be used in some capacity, but it does some hacky behavior to try to get the 'state to apply' (aka resetting the grid entirely and getting data within ongridready).
I've attempted something similar with no luck, and honestly don't know if it's worth continuing. Is there some functionality that would allow me to apply grid state to a grid, or would I have to do some mapping behavior to transform 'gridState' and it's respective properties to 'columnState' to apply (and so on).
Edit ---
I ended up using column state, maybe it will help someone. I wish grid state was a simple solution to interact with db restoration but from what i could tell when implementing it it was more to do with navigating to/from the grid when you are working within an app where
it gets removed from the dom during the user flow.
<AgGridReact ...
        onColumnRowGroupChanged={handleColumnRowGroupChanged}
        onColumnVisible={handleColumnVisibilityChange}
        onColumnPinned={handlePinningChange}
        onColumnResized={handleColumnSizingChange}
        onColumnMoved={handleColumnOrderChange}
/>
    const handleApplyState = useCallback(
      ({ api, source }: { api: GridApi<SpPmProduct>; source: string }) => {
        if (
          source === 'viewportSizeFeature' ||
          source === 'api' ||
          source === 'gridInitializing' ||
          source === 'gridOptionsChanged'
        ) {
          return;
        }
        const columnState = api.getColumnState();
        setTableGridColumnState(columnState);
      },
      [setTableGridColumnState]
    );

 const handlePinningChange = useCallback(
      (params: ColumnPinnedEvent<SpPmProduct>) => {
        handleApplyState(params);
      },
      [handleApplyState]
    );

    const handleColumnVisibilityChange = useCallback(
      (params: ColumnVisibleEvent<SpPmProduct>) => {
        handleApplyState(params);
      },
      [handleApplyState]
    );

    const handleColumnSizingChange = useCallback(
      (params: ColumnResizedEvent<SpPmProduct>) => {
        if (params.finished) {
          handleApplyState(params);
        }
      },
      [handleApplyState]
    );
    const handleColumnOrderChange = useCallback(
      (params: ColumnMovedEvent<SpPmProduct>) => {
        if (params.finished) {
          handleApplyState(params);
        }
      },
      [handleApplyState]
    );

    const handleColumnRowGroupChanged = useCallback(
      (params: ColumnRowGroupChangedEvent<SpPmProduct>) => {
        handleApplyState(params);
      },
      [handleApplyState]
    );


 useDidUpdate(() => {
      if (tableGridColumnState) {
        gridRef?.current?.api?.applyColumnState({
          state: tableGridColumnState,
          applyOrder: true,
        });
      } else {
        gridRef?.current?.api?.resetColumnState();
      }
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [tableGridColumnState]); // this is strictly to apply column state when tableGridColumnState changes



This uses the "hacky" approach in the docs of destroying and re-creating the grid with a new initial state, but I am using the below to copy grid state, save it as text via a pop-up modal (can instead ship and retrieve to/from a DB; that's also on my roadmap), and then restore grid state from an arbitrary string representing the Gride State object.
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
const [configTextAreaValue, setConfigTextAreaValue] = useState('');
const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState<GridState>();
const [gridVisible, setGridVisible] = useState(true);

...

//Grid state copy
const onConfigCopy = useCallback(() => {
    let state = gridRef.current!.api.getState();
    let stateString = JSON.stringify(state);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(stateString)
}, []);

//Grid state input
const handleTextareaChange = (event: any) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setConfigTextAreaValue(event.target.value);
};

const onConfigInput = useCallback((config: string) => {

    //Save inputted config to initial state
    let inputtedConfig: GridState = JSON.parse(configTextAreaValue);
    setInitialState(inputtedConfig)

    //Destroy and re-render the grid with initial state
    setGridVisible(false);
    setTimeout(() => {
        setGridVisible(true);
        setModalOpen(false)
    });
}, [configTextAreaValue]);

...


return (
    <div className="mb-4">
        <div>
            <div
                className="ag-theme-quartz" // applying the Data Grid theme
                style={{ height: 500 }} // the Data Grid will fill the size of the parent container
            >
                {gridVisible && (
                    <AgGridReact
                        ref={gridRef}
                        rowData={rowData}
                        columnDefs={colDefs}
                        loading={loading}
                        rowGroupPanelShow='always'
                        sideBar={sideBar}
                        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                        initialState={initialState}
                        aggFuncs={aggFuncs}
                    />
                )}
                
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
)

Not as clean as updating the state, but this was better than parsing out individual state objects and updating in turn. (Also, I'm not sure if every option is available that way.)
